Convertir coordenadas WGS84 (CATASTRO) a coordenadas de Google Maps
Estoy realizando un proyecto y me han proporcionado las coordenadas de las propiedades según el catastro de España, que vienen en formato WGS84 (553286.55 4678790.51) y me gustaría poder convertirlas en coordenadas para poder posicionar en Google Maps.
Alguien sabría decirme algún algoritmo de conversión de un formato a otro.
Muchas gracias.


Primero identifica la zona UTM: Cada par de coordenadas UTM está asociado a una zona UTM específica. España se encuentra principalmente en las zonas UTM 29N, 30N y 31N. Debes saber en cuál de estas zonas se encuentra tu coordenada.

Segundo convierte coordenadas UTM a geográficas: Utiliza un algoritmo o una herramienta para realizar la conversión de coordenadas UTM a coordenadas geográficas. Puedes usar herramientas en línea o librerías específicas en diversos lenguajes de programación. Te muestro como puedes hacerlo con python:


Primero, instala la librería pyproj si no la tienes ya instalada.
pip install pyproj

Con este codigo podras convertir las coordenadas
from pyproj import Proj, transform

# Coordenadas UTM (WGS84)
utm_x = 553286.55
utm_y = 4678790.51
zone_number = 30  # Número de zona UTM
zone_letter = 'N'  # Letra de zona UTM, 'N' para el hemisferio norte

# Crear un objeto de proyección para la zona UTM específica
utm_proj = Proj(proj='utm', zone=zone_number, datum='WGS84')

# Crear un objeto de proyección para coordenadas geográficas
wgs84_proj = Proj(proj='latlong', datum='WGS84')

# Convertir de UTM a coordenadas geográficas
longitude, latitude = transform(utm_proj, wgs84_proj, utm_x, utm_y)

print(f"Latitud: {latitude}, Longitud: {longitude}")

PD: Como ya te he comentado hay paginas web que ofrecen este servicio como puede ser esta pero no es el objetivo de este sitio buscar recomendacion sobre productos.

Muchas gracias.
Funciona perfectamente.
Un saludo

@JairoD.S.N. Entonces favor marcar la respuesta como aceptada, saludos
